# Make a string encoder in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string, ascii, encode

I am a beginner of learning how to code and I want to write a string coder. By string coder, I mean if we input the word "abc", the output is "cde". That is, every character move to plus 2.

I'm able to convert a single character, for example: input "a" -> output "c".

But I'm not sure how to input a word instead of a character.

```
char passWord[40];
NSLog(@" Plz enter the password");
scanf("%s",passWord);

NSString *tempCode = [NSString stringWithCString:passWord encoding:1];

//NSLog(@"test %@", tempCode);

int decode, asciiCode = [tempCode characterAtIndex:0];

//NSLog(@"test %d", asciiCode);

decode = asciiCode + 2;

NSString *decodeNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", decode];

NSLog(@"%@", decodeNum);
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Just to clarify, what happens if the character is "y" or "z"?

Comment: Hi, input: y -> {, input: z -> |. The origin question is defined by ascII code. That's why I use ascII as an int variable.